# How to get records from DynamoDB table based on list type attribute, without scan operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have the following situation, with similar to this DynamoDB table definition:

```
{
    "TableName": "Table",
    "KeySchema": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "Id",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "CompoundSortKey",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "Id",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "CompoundSortKey",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        },      
        {
            "AttributeName": "AttributeId1",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "AttributeId2",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ],
    "LocalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
            "IndexName": "Id-AttributeId1-index",
            "KeySchema": [
                {
                    "AttributeName": "Id",
                    "KeyType": "HASH"
                },
                {
                    "AttributeName": "AttributeId1",
                    "KeyType": "RANGE"
                }
            ],
            "Projection": {
                "ProjectionType": "ALL"
            }
        },
        {
            "IndexName": "Id-AttributeId2-index",
            "KeySchema": [
                {
                    "AttributeName": "Id",
                    "KeyType": "HASH"
                },
                {
                    "AttributeName": "AttributeId2",
                    "KeyType": "RANGE"
                }
            ],
            "Projection": {
                "ProjectionType": "ALL"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
    }
}
```

Each record beside the defined attributes consisted of additional property, map type with few attributes.

Currently, I am facing a situation where I need to retrieve records based on one of the attributes in this map, this attribute is list type (Precisely I need to find records, which have some value inside this list).

I need a suggestion how to approach this problem, I have read so far about global secondary indexes, but I am not sure if my case applies to them since the attribute I need to filter based on is list type.

I am using C# language for records fetching, but my problem requires most likely table definition changes. Probably it is worth mentioning that I am trying to avoid full table scan operation.

UPDATE:

Data which is inside this list can be understood as a "tag". It means that multiple documents inside this table might have the same tag.

I have a situation where I have to filter out all documents which have this specific tag as one of the elements inside this list

Answer (score 0):

You can't query DynamoDB based on an arbitrary attribute. For efficient queries you need an index: that means either the implicit index formed by the partition key + sort key on your table, a local index formed by the partition key + some other attribute as a sort key, or a global secondary index formed by any one or two attributes on the table.

The catch: indexed attributes must be either of type String, or of type Number - maps and lists are not supported as indexed attributes.

This means that if you need efficient queries you must rethink the schema. Values that would be stored in the list, or map attribute you want to index must be converted to a top-level string or numeric attribute. Exactly how to do that depends on the specifics of the data you're working with (which is not specified in the question).

Comment: Updated original question